# refreshing javascript code every 5 seconds the browser crashes

Tags: javascript, browser, crash

I need to read json every 5 seconds, I have another 10 and over every 60.  After a while the browser crashes.

```
var Clock = {    
        seconds: 1,
        start: function () {
            var that = this;
            var aradios=[], acoches=[], velcoches=[],nradios=[], ncoches=[];
            this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                // leo todos los radios y su posicion
                $.getJSON("radiosenmaparemain.php", function(data){
                    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                        var posradio = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lon);
                        aradios.push(posradio);
                        nradios.push(data[i].idcolaborador);
                    }
                });
                // leo todos los coches y su posicion
                $.getJSON("todosenmapa.php", function(data2){
                    for (var n = 0, len = data2.length; n < len; n++) {
                        var poscoche = new google.maps.LatLng(data2[n].lat, data2[n].lon);
                        acoches.push(poscoche);
                        ncoches.push(data2[n].idpiloto);
                        velcoches.push(data2[n].vel);
                    }
                }); 

                for(var i in acoches){

                    for(var n in aradios){
                        // alert(n + " " + i);
                        var distancia = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(acoches[i],aradios[n]);
                        var cdistancia=distancia.toString();
                        var li = cdistancia.lastIndexOf(".");

                        cdistancia=cdistancia.substr(0,li);
                        var span=(parseInt(ncoches[i]))+'-'+(parseInt(nradios[n]));

                        $('#km-'+span).text(cdistancia+" m");
                        $('#tm-'+span).text(calculasegundos(distancia/velcoches[i]));
                        // alert('#km-'+span);
                    }
                }

        }, 10000)
    },
    pause: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval); delete this.interval;
    },
    resume: function() {
        if(!this.interval) this.start();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please fix code statements

Comment: hello, I do not understand your answer, besides being new'm Spanish. You can clearing that. Thank you